# SQL Report Builder 3.0 date parameter need assistance

Tags: sql, datetime, parameters, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to create a Report in SQL Report Builder 3.0 and I need your help to add a "Parameter" filter for the Report which will run the report and display rows with this parameter filter values.  The parameters I want are `Day` and `Week`.

Now the first, `Day` would display rows using `TestingTime` (a column from the database table, its a datetime column) as the date column from `getdate()` minus 24 hours.

The second, `Week` would display rows with getdate() minus 7 days.

I have one DataSet query that runs the report right now that looks like this:

```
select ElementTesterMeasData.RecID, WindingProdData.Machine,
       ElementTesterMeasData.Felkod, ElementTesterMeasData.MeasP2AntalClear,
       ElementTesterMeasData.TestingTime
from DRYDCAP.dbo.WindingProdData
  full outer JOIN ElementTesterMeasData
    on ElementTesterMeasData.RecID=WindingProdData.SerialNumber
where Machine in (@Maskin)
  and Felkod in (@Felkoder)
order by Testingtime desc
```

The part `where Machine in (@Maskin) and Felkod in (@Felkoder)` points to 2 other parameters that i use in the report to filter what rows to display.

What would I have to add to this Query (or new dataset query) to make this work? And what would I have to add to Parameters that filters the returning rows with data from **NOW** -1 day back, or **NOW** -1 week back?  If something is unclear I will try to explain the best I can.

BR,

Mikael